# How to cancel an HTML5 drag (and drop) operation using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to cancel an HTML5 drag operation based on some condition. I have tried to search this but found nothing useful. It seems that there is no way to cancel an HTML5 drag and drop using JavaScript. `return`ing `false` in the `dragstart` doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can cancel it by calling `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler.
For example this should work:

```
<p id="p1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);">This element is draggable.</p>

<script>
var enableDragDrop = true;
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
    if (!enableDragDrop) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    console.log("dragStart");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something tricky to make it work, for I do not know how to stop a drag from js, but you can fake a drag with `mousedown`,`mousedown`,`mouseup` and a `isDragging` flag

some code look like:

```js
var isDragging = false
var fakeDraggingElement
var currentDragging

$('#item').mousedown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  isDragging = true
  currentDragging = this
  
  //change your cursor and make it loos like dragging
  $('#parent').css({cursor: 'move'})
  //fake dragging element
  fakeDraggingElement = $(this).clone().css({
    opacity:0.5,
    position:'absolute',
    top:e.pageY+offsetY, //parent offset
    left:e.pageX+offsetX,//parent offset
  }).appendTo(parent)
}).mousemove(function(e){
  if(!isDragging){
    return
  }
  fakeDraggingElement.css({
    top:e.pageY+offsetY, //parent offset
    left:e.pageX+offsetX,//parent offset
  })
}).mousedown(function(e){
  if(!isDragging){
    return
  }
  cancleDrag()
  //your old drop
  ondrop(currentDragging,e.target)
})

function cancleDrag(){
  isDragging = false
  $(currentDragging).remove()
  currentDragging = undefined
}
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT:
got it. Its a bit roundabout, but works. Take advantage of the fact that the drag event is a cancellable mouse event, and cancelling it stops all further drag actions. Create a drag event on your condition and call `preventDefault()`. The following cancels it after 3 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("drag").ondrag = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.ondrag = null;
    return false;
};},3000);
```

Note first that I clear all `ondrag` events after it is cancelled, which you may need to adjust if you need other `ondrag` events, and second that this truly cancels all parts of the drag, so you don't get an `ondragend` event after, as shown in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/aCkbR/

Source: HTML5 Spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#dndevents

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. In Chrome, I can drag even after 3 seconds have passed. In FF, it doesn't drag at all (in the first place).